# Is there a 3rd-party buildfarm for pre-release tests?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

As the ROS buildfarm does not perform pre-release tests anymore (see http://answers.ros.org/question/219500/no-more-prerelease-test-on-the-buildfarm/ ), I tried to setup a  virtual maschine with docker to run the tests locally. Unfortunately I have a 32-bit system and docker requires a 64-bit system. I'd like to avoid reinstalling my whole system just to run the tests.

So: Is there any 3rd-party buildfarm/cloud/server/host where I can run the tests on?

Regards,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220741/is-there-a-3rd-party-buildfarm-for-pre-release-tests?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of anyone running that as a service. You could probably rig up a travis build to do this for you, or launch a 64 bit VM in with a cloud provider.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-03-03**:
Ok, thank you. We were thinking about a cloud provider, too. But in the meantime I have a 64-bit system and I did the tests on this machine.